# How do I sort data stored in Hive by date on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, sorting, datetime

I would like to sort them so that they are in new date order.

- It is currently stored as follows

```
count = 5;

DateTime now = DateTime.now();
final String nowTime = DateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss').format(DateTime.now());

recordCountBox.put(nowTime,'${count}',);
```

- Print sample

```
'2023/05/12 09:30:04':'5',
'2023/05/10 10:59:04':'5',
'2023/05/11 12:59:04':'5',
```

- How to display

```
 child: ValueListenableBuilder(
                            valueListenable: recordCountBox!.listenable(),
                            builder: (context, Box<String> recordBox, _) {
                              return ListView.separated(
                                  itemCount: recordBox.keys.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
                                    final key = recordBox.keys.toList()[i];
                                    final note = recordBox.get(key);
                                    final count = int.parse(note.toString());
```